# Explicit piecewise linear approximation of a function of 4 variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics

I have a table of numbers for fixed values of 4 parameters $x, y, z, t$, at this $x$ belongs to finite set of natural numbers, $y\in\{1;2\}$, $z\in\{5;10;15;20;25\}$ and $t\in\{1,2,3\}$. Is there a method to construct such a function $f$ that inserting particular values from the table, $r=f(x,y,z,t)$ will coincide with my data.

The data are of this type, for example, $f(27,1,20,3)=46.08$, $f(35,1,20,3)=63.9$, $f(32,1,5,3)=17.24$, etc.

**Update**

I need explicit piecewise linear approximation formula for $f(x,y,z,t)$ on the basis of known $f_i$, $i\in\{1;1240\}$. The formula for functions with 3 variables will of help as well.

Comment: Are you looking for a particular type of function? Does your function have to return _interpolated_ values too?

Comment: I am not sure about interpolation, because we have 4 variables and it seems to be very hard to construct interpolating function, doesn`t it?

Comment: Well, it depends what kind of funcion you need and what you are looking for once you have it. I do not think I can help you much with this, but giving some more context will make other users understand better what you need.

Comment: I need only the function, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $t$, the $x$ range is fixed for both $y$s, therefore
$$
f(x,y,z)\sim\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^5\sum_{k=1}^2f(x_i,y_j,z_k)L_i(x)L_j(y)L_k(z),
$$
where $L_i$ is Lagrange`s polynomial:
$$
L_i(h)=\prod_{l=1,~ l\neq i}^n\frac{h-h_l}{h_i-h_l}.
$$